# php space in href link

Tags: php, html

php code

```
 echo "<td><a href=?V*".$row['rec_title']."> ". $row['rec_title'] . "</a></td>";
```

html code

```
<a href=?V*Venison with Frumenty(British)> Venison with Frumenty(British)</td>
```

but when i click on the -> Venison with frumenty (british)
the link is generate half link  example  http://ex.com/?Vension

and i want complete link like that  http://ex.com/?Venison with Frumenty(British)

how to fix this issue please help me to fix this issue

Comment: you may need to add quotes after the `href=` and before `>`

Comment: Maybe encoding http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to achieve the same.

```
echo "<td><a href=?V*".urlencode($row['rec_title'])."> ". $row['rec_title'] . "</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use urlencode (http://php.net/urlencode) to display links like that:

```
 echo "<td><a href=\"?V*".urlencode($row['rec_title'])."\"> ". $row['rec_title'] . "</a></td>";
```

urlencode will replace spaces with `%20` which is the two-digit hex representation for a space.  You should get in the habit of always using `urlencode` in these scenarios.

Also, as Devang and Class said - don't forget your quotes around your attribute values.  Instead of `<a href=something></a>` do `<a href="something"></a>`