# Getting a string with a space in between in echo

Tags: php, html

I have a code in html that allow me to get string with a space in between such as "Play game".

In html:

```
<li><a href="allProduct.php?category=Play Game">Play Game</a></li>
```

But I couldn't do so in echo(), I only managed to get the word "play":

```
    echo("<table width=80%>
    <tr>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="allProduct.php?category=Play Game">Play Game</a</li>
    </ul>
    </tr>");
```

Comment: put `&nbsp;` between play and game..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15308674/2274209

Answer (score 1):

Note, although most browser will just `eat` that whitespaces in urls, they are not allowed per standard. You can refer to this [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), which says:

> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a + sign.

In PHP use [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode the whitespace into a `+`:

```
$encoded = urlencode('allProduct.php?category=Play Game');
// will give you : allProduct.php?category=Play+Game
```

Also you cannot use double quotes to surround a string that contains double quotes. I would use single quotes to surround it.

Full example:

```
echo('<table width=80%>
<tr>
<ul>
    <li><a href="' . urlencode('allProduct.php?category=Play Game') .'">Play Game</a</li>
</ul>
</tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are surrounding your echo string in double quotes while also using double quotes inside the string itself. You can solve this by either enclosing your echo string in single quotes, or by escaping the double quotes inside your string using a backslash. (Like so: \")

Edit: you may also want to remove the space from "Play" and "Game". Use PHP's [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to achieve this. You can also use a `&nbsp;` instead, as suggested by another poster.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper escaping of your string:

```
echo("<table width=80%>
<tr>
<ul>
    <li><a href=\"allProduct.php?category=Play%20Game\">Play Game</a</li>
</ul>
</tr>");
```

You also have to encode your whitespaces in URL-format with `%20`.

Comment: Is works.
Can I check with you for input tage does it work this way too?
<input type=submit name=insert value=\"New%20Product\"> I tried but it did not work

Comment: @benylim in inputs you don't need to escape the whitespace, only in urls.

Comment: But when I put it as <input type=submit name=insert value=New Product> it only show the word "New"

Comment: don't forget the quotes: `<input type="submit" name="insert" value="New Product">` (and to escape them)

Comment: That was it in echo tag. when I put the "" it will have error

Comment: @benylim Clearly: `<input type=submit name=insert value=\"New Product\">`. I said to not forget escaping ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo('<table width=80%>
<tr>
<ul>
    <li><a href="allProduct.php?category=Play%20Game">Play Game</a</li>
</ul>
</tr>');
```

Change your double quotes for single quotes and it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use single ' for echo.
Than you can use normal " for HTML

```
echo '<tag class="xyz">...</tag>';
```

By the way: You should not use spaces in links.

You can - and should use - the appropriate methods for it.
in your case

```
urlencode('Music Albums')
```

which encodes the space accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this

```
echo("<table width=80%>
        <tr>
        <ul>
        <li><a href='allProduct.php?category=Play Game'>Play Game</a</li>
        </ul>
        </tr>");
```